# How does passport validity affect touristic Schengen stays?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, visa-free-entry

My friend entered Germany under a visa waiver with a passport expiring in 4 months at the time. At the time she hadn't been in Schengen region for over 90 days since her last exit, so I believe she should qualify for 90 days of stay upon entry.

Her initial plan was to stay 3 weeks but the plans changed and now wants to stay a bit longer, likely closer to 2-3 months (but less than 90 days).

She's however worried that because her passport is expiring in 4 months, and as Germany requires that when entering her planned leave date will leave more than 3 months of validity on her passport.

[image]

Can she stay upwards of 90 days or can she only stay until her passport has 3 months left?

Answer (score 2):

The requirement only applies at the time of entering and if her plans changed, then the plans changed. As long as the passport is still valid when leaving, she should not expect any problems or issuer.

Comment: Indeed this is one of the reasons for the required extra 3 months validity period: to avoid situations where a traveler's plans change and they are stuck in a foreign country with an expired passport.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected too. I'll accept the answer when she leaves successfully.

Comment: @jsl Perhaps, perhaps not. If the only reason was that you should not end up with an expired passport if you decide to stay longer, it would be sufficient that the passport was valid 90 days at the date of entry (you are not allowed to stay longer anyway) and it would not been necessary to require a three month validity beyond the expected date of exit.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, think of the 3 months as 90 days with a safety buffer. The visitor could be hospitalized, unable to travel. A volcano could disrupt air traffic. Whatever. Three months is a compromise between 'long enough' and 'not too intrusive.'